# Find an integer $a$ such that $a\sqrt{2} $ has a given decimal part

Tags: arithmetic, decimal-expansion

Suppose I want to find integers such that when I multiply it by an irrational number (e.g $\sqrt{2}$), its decimal part contains 0.14159... as starting digits. How do I find them? Is there a pattern for the digits of such numbers?

Comment: I don't think we can avoid searching altogether, but we can search in ways that are more efficient than just trying $a=1,2,3,\ldots$.

Comment: @hardmath: that is exactly what I want to do, find an efficient searching of such numbers.

Comment: A little more than [one million digits of $\sqrt{2}$](https://apod.nasa.gov/htmltest/gifcity/sqrt2.1mil) can be searched on that webpage, and the string "14159" appears seven times (the first time is about 40% down the page).

Answer (score 3):

It is fairly easy to compute $\sqrt{2}$ to arbitrarily high precision.  See for example [this page](https://apod.nasa.gov/htmltest/gifcity/sqrt2.1mil) reporting a little more than one million digits.

If we are searching for a fixed initial string of length $n$, then of course if it can be located in $\sqrt{2}$ further along, that string can be brought to the front by multiplying by the appropriate power of ten.  One then has a (not necessarily minimum) solution for $a$.  In this case the string "14159" is found seven times within the first million digits.

Finding the minimum value of $a$ seems to be a difficult computational challenge.

Comment: So you mean that every given string of digits is contained in $\sqrt{2}$ ? Do other irrational numbers of the form $\sqrt{b}$ where b is integer have this property ?

Comment: @TungNguyen It is not known. "Almost all" numbers have this property, yet it hasn't been proven for any particular number except those constructed specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, your trick solved my question for the $\sqrt{2}$ case. I would upvote it. But I'm looking for solutions that can be extended to other irrational numbers of the form $\sqrt{b}$, and is within a given range ( abs(a) can't be too large). I'm thinking along the line of significant digits and such. The latter digits of $\sqrt{2}$ don't contribute much to the product, thus we don't need full precision of $\sqrt{2}$ anyway.

Comment: It generalizes to other numbers of the form $\sqrt{b}$ in that the Newton iteration (doubling precision with each step) makes it cheap to compute a large number of decimal places.  You gave no info about how the magnitude of  $a$ should be limited, so I'm not sure I can address that concern.

Comment: I want the magnitude of a to be within 10^13. The product should have as many decimal digits of pi as possible. Searching every possible value of $a$ for a given string is too expensive.

Answer (score 3):

The [equidistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) says that if $\alpha$ is an irrational number, then the sequence of fractional parts, $k\alpha-\lfloor k\alpha\rfloor$, for $k\in\mathbb{N}$, is equidistributed in $[0,1]$.  In particular, the interval $(0.14159,0.14160)$ will, in the limit, be visited on average once every $100{,}000$ multiples.  More generally, any opening string of $n$ digits will occur on average once every $10^n$ multiples.

Comment: In my understanding, your theorem asserts the existence of such k for a given n digits fractional part for every 10^n integers. For large strings, (13 digits for examples), I have to search for k from 1 to 10^13. It's not quite efficient.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the following approach. Suppose we have an irrational number $\alpha$ and want to have some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that the fractional part of $n\alpha$ equals some goal $x$ with certain precision.

1. Start with $n=0$.
2. Take $q$, the denominator of the first [convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) of $\alpha$. Find the **step size**: number from $(-0.5,0.5]$ equivalent modulo 1 to the fractional part $\{q\alpha\}$.
3. Add step to $n\alpha$ (that is, add $q$ to $n$) as many times as it takes to get $\{n\alpha\}$ as close to the goal as possible, *without wrapping around 1*. For example, if step size is 0.13 and the goal is 0.69, then add 5 times. It may turn out (like it does with $\alpha=\sqrt2$ and $x=0.14159$) that making even one step takes us farther away from the goal than we were; then don't make it at all, i.e., make 0 steps.
4. Take the next convergent and repeat.
5. Move on to the next convergent, and continue in this manner until we reach $x$ with desired precision.

This method is guaranteed to work on any irrational $\alpha$ and is not hinged on the hypothesis of its [normality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number). Also, it is pretty fast. Denominators always grow exponentially or faster, so you'll need at most $O(n)$ convergents to achieve the precision of $n$ digits. As for finding the *minimum* possible solution, I don't think it guarantees that (why would it?), but I expect it to fall reasonably close - that is, less than an order of magnitude away.

**Upd.** I've ran some tests and behold, it **does** find the minimum solution more often than not.

$$\begin{array}{lll}
\text{Goal} & n\text{(my method)} & n\text{(min.)} \\
0.14159 & 176827 & 96045 \\
0.71828 & 59937  & 59937 \\
0.73205 & 28067  & 28067 \\
0.61803 & 2126   & 2126  \\
0.33333 & 76162  & 76162 \\
\end{array}$$

Now what about complexity?

$$\begin{array}{lll}
\text{Goal} & n & \text{Convergents used} \\
0.1415  & 9522       & 12 \\
0.14159 & 176827     & 15 \\
0.141592 & 1118491   & 17 \\
0.1415926 & 8880289  & 19 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: I'm not familiar with continued fraction and convergent. This approach seems to work !. I haven't understood it yet ( I will learn more about it), may I ask the complexity of this algorithm though, is it efficient? And does it output the minimum n ?

Comment: Note that the special form of the [continued fraction for $\sqrt{2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Square_roots) means that the denominators $k_n$ of the convergents satisfy $k_n = 2\cdot k_{n-1} + k_{n-2}$, as discussed at [Convergents of square root of 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730349/convergents-of-square-root-of-2).  Growth of the denominators is thus like $(1+\sqrt{2})^n$.

Answer (score -2):

We can show that there exists no integer such that $a \cdot \sqrt{2}$ has the full decimal part of $\pi$. Suppose there were such an integer $a$ such that $a \cdot \sqrt{2} = B + \pi -3$, where $B \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, we would  also have that $a \cdot \sqrt{2} + 3 -B = \pi$. But then notice that the LHS is an algebraic number, whereas the RHS is a transcendental number. Contradiction.

Comment: OP asked only that $a\sqrt(2)$ have a given decimal part, not a given value entirely.

Comment: You are correct. See my edit.

Comment: 647659 times $\sqrt{2}$ has 14159 as its starting decimal part, for example.