# How do we choose/find the rational sequence that is asymptotic to an irrational one?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I read that to any irrational sequence we can assign at least one rational sequence which is asymptotic to it.
The fact that it is asymptotic I think implies that the rational sequence approximates the irrational one as much as we like.
But I am not clear how we find one such rational sequence?
E.g. if we have (just as an example) the expression $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt 2}$ a direct sequence to interpret it is:
$\sqrt{2.4}, \sqrt{2.41}, \sqrt{2.414}, ...$ and all the terms are irrationals.

But in general how do we choose/find the rational sequence to represent it instead which is asymptotic to the irrational one?
Would we pick just a rational approximation of each irrational term choosing up to an aribtrary number of digits after the decimal? E.g.
$1.549193338, 1.552417469 ...$?
These are the 9 first digits of $\sqrt{2.4}, \sqrt{2.41}$

Comment: You could always take the decimal expansion of a real number $x$ as a starting point. So for example the sequence $3$, $3.1$, $3.14$, $\ldots$ converges to $\pi$.

Comment: @littleO: Isn't this what I also do in my example? I was wondering if it is strictly correct

Comment: You could just use the decimal expansion of $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt 2}$ directly. $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt 2} = 1.5537739740\ldots$ is the limit of the sequence $1, 1.5, 1.55, 1.553, 1.5537, \ldots$. No need to involve the decimal digits of $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @JairTaylor The original problem talks about a **sequence of irrationals** which we want to approximate with a sequence of rationals. That's why the OP choose $\sqrt{2.4}, \sqrt{2.41},\sqrt{2.414}, \ldots$

Comment: The OP has chosen as his irrational sequence one that has a limit. This blurs the distinction between the rational sequence being assymptotic to that sequence, and a rational sequence which converges to the same limit, for which continued fractions is an ideal construction. Does the original assertion also cover an irrational sequence that does not converge? They exist, as I can think of a trivial example, 1+root(2), 2+root(2)...n+root(2)

Comment: @JairTaylor: by the way is $1,  1.5, 1.55, 1.553, 1.5537$ is it also a series of some sequence? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4420012/in-real-numbers-does-the-series-converging-to-them-have-a-generating-sequence

Comment: @Neil_UK: What is the difference between rational sequence being asymptotic to the irrational sequence vs rational sequence converges to the limit the irrational sequence represents? It seems to me the same thing?

Comment: They *are* the same thing – provided the irrational sequence actually has a limit. The first sentence says “any irrational sequence”, which includes sequences that do not have a limit. Even for such sequences, there are still asymptotic rational sequences, as demonstrated by the answers.

Comment: @BrianDrake: ah I see. Thank you for pointing that out. I didn't realize that. So if the irrational sequence does not approximate an irrational number (i.e. have a limit) then we find the rational sequence that is asymptotic with continued fractions?

Comment: @Jim Your last comment has an error (not strictly relevant to the question): even if an irrational sequence *converges* (to use the proper term), it may not converge to an irrational number. For example, the irrational sequence $\pi / n$ converges to the rational number $0$. As for continued fractions, they are a fine way of approximating a single irrational *number*, but I am not sure how they are relevant to approximating an arbitrary irrational *sequence*.

Comment: @BrianDrake: Besides $0$ is there any other rational number that an irrational sequence could converse?

Comment: Of course: $\{1 + \frac{\pi}{n}\}$ converges to $1$, and $1$ can be replaced by any other rational (or indeed irrational) number to create a sequence that converges to that number.

Answer (score 6):

If $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of real numbers, then for each $n\in\Bbb N$, there is some rational number $q_n\in\left(a_n,a_n+\frac1n\right)$. So, $(q_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of rational numbers and $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n-q_n)=0$.

Comment: How does this relate to the irrational sequence I would want to represent? Both $(a_n)$ and $(q_n)$ are rational sequences

Comment: At which point did I write that $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a rational sequence?

Comment: I am sorry, I misunderstood it! When you say $q_n\in\left(a_n,a_n+\frac1n\right)$ how did we choose that? Couldn't it have been e.g. $q_n \in (a_n,a_n+\frac{1}{10^n})$ for instance? Or something else?

Comment: Sure it could. I have used the sequence $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$. You have suggested the sequence $\left(\frac1{10^n}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$. Both will work. What matters is that it is a sequence that converges to $0$, so that $\lim_{n\to\infty(a_n-q_n)=0$.

Comment: So there is besides diminishing difference between the 2 sequences there is no other criteria right? This means then that my example in the post is wrong because I am using fixed $9$ decimal digits per term hence they can not converge to $0$?

Comment: I don't see the need for any other condition.

Comment: If you just fix the first $9$ decimals, then you can't be sure that the sequence of rationals that you get is asymptotic to the original sequence.

Comment: "there is some rational number $q_n\in\left(a_n,a_n+\frac1n\right)$"  this recipe gives the interval and assumes the rational exists but is there an algorithmic way to find the actual rational (first one I guess?) in the interval?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135316/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-jim).

Comment: @OliverDiaz: What computer methods are these?

Comment: Of the answers currently visible, this answer was the first. So, even though it does not actually answer the main question, perhaps it was a good answer at the time. Still, the main question is not particularly difficult to answer, and no attempt was made since then. I do not think this is worth an upvote.

Answer (score 5):

Your idea of using the decimal expansion is good and can be explicitly written as this $$a_n = \frac{1}{10^n}\left\lfloor10^n\ x_n\right\rfloor$$

It readily follows from the the properties of the floor function that $$x_n-\frac{1}{10^n}< a_n \le x_n$$ which proves that $a_n$ is asymptotic to $x_n$.

Notice that the sequence $10^n$ could be changed by any other sequence of integers tending to infinity. May be the simplest would be $$a_n = \frac{1}{n}\left\lfloor n\ x_n\right\rfloor$$

Comment: +1 This seems like the most elegant answer possible. However, we are not limited to sequences of integers: $10^n$ could be replaced by any other sequence of real numbers tending to infinity.

Comment: Is $x_n$ the term of the irrational sequence? Also I thought the floor function is used only in division. I am confused with having it as part of multiplication $\lfloor10^n\ x_n\rfloor$

Comment: Yes $(x_n)$ is the irrational sequence. And, do you know what the floor function is? It's defined for all real numbers.

Comment: You are right! My bad, stupid question about the floor!

Comment: So if I understand correctly it is the floor that makes it the nearest rational and we divide by $10$ to get rid of the multiplication right? Hence it is $\le x_n$ due to using floor but why is it $a_n \gt x_n - \frac{1}{{10}^n}$? It is not obvious to me.

Comment: Obviously, I should have said that $10^n$ could be replaced by any other sequence of **rational** numbers, so that $a_n$ would also be rational.

Comment: @Jim It sounds like you do not have a good understanding of the floor function. See [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4420691/843797).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the irrational sequence

$$\langle a_n \rangle ~: a_n = ~n \times \pi, ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$$

In a manner very similar to that *suggested* in the original posting, 
for $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ 
define the function $f(n)$ to be $\pi$ accurate to $(10)^n$ decimal places, 
where the decimal expression of $\pi$ is **truncated** (rather than rounded) 
after the $[(10)^n]$-th decimal place.

Now define

$$\langle b_n\rangle ~: ~b_n = n \times f(n), ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$$

Then $~\displaystyle \langle b_n \rangle$ is a rational sequence that is asymptotic to the irrational sequence $~\displaystyle \langle a_n\rangle.$

---

**Edit**
Now, vary the above example.  Instead of the irrational sequence $~\displaystyle \langle a_n \rangle~$ defined above, let $~\displaystyle \langle a_n \rangle~$ be any sequence of numbers, where each element of the sequence is irrational.

Then, in a manner very similar to the example at the start of my answer, you can construct the corresponding rational sequence $~\displaystyle \langle b_n \rangle~$, where $b_n$ represents the first $(10)^n$ decimal places (with truncation) of the irrational number $a_n$.

Then, as before, you will have that $~\displaystyle \langle b_n \rangle$ is a rational sequence that is asymptotic to the irrational sequence $~\displaystyle \langle a_n\rangle.$

Comment: 1) is the a difference between *truncating* and rounding down? 2) "Instead of the irrational sequence $~\displaystyle \langle a_n \rangle~$ defined above, let $~\displaystyle \langle a_n \rangle~$ be any sequence of numbers, where each element of the sequence is irrational" I don't understand this statement. Isn't saying a sequence ${a}$ is irrational exactly the same thing as saying ${a}$ is a sequence where each element is irrational?

Comment: @Jim responding to your questions 1 at a time: [1] I agree that technically, you could have the terms rounded rather than truncated.  I chose truncation only because it seemed easier for me to visualize the corresponding error.  That is, if $a_n$ (irrational) is greater than $b_n$ (rational) and $a_n - b_n < 10^{-n}$ then it becomes clearer, in my mind that $\langle b_n\rangle$ is asymptotic to $\langle a_n\rangle.$  So, I opted for a strategy that permitted me a clearer vision. ...see next comment

Comment: @Jim [2] I have a great deal of ignorance in the area of managing sequences.  I chose (for example) the syntax *each term is irrational* only to ensure that there was no ambiguity.  For all that I know, the alternative syntax that $\langle a_n\rangle$ *is an irrational sequence* might actually mean the same thing.  I am simply ignorant, in this area.

Answer (score 1):

This is an expanded version of [jjagmath’s excellent but terse answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4420413/843797), with a lot more explanation.

Consider the question’s example:

\begin{equation}
\{\sqrt{2.4}, \sqrt{2.41}, \dots\} = \{1.549\dots, 1.552\dots, \dots\}
\end{equation}

Using the question’s idea of choosing an arbitrary number of digits after the decimal point (where we need to use *arbitrarily many* digits as the sequence goes on to make the new sequence asymptotic to the original one), we can choose one digit for the first term, two digits for the second term, and so on. In general, we choose $n$ digits for the $n^\text{th}$ term $x_n$.

In other words, we drop all the digits after the first $n$ decimal places. Luckily, we have a well-known function that *almost* does this: the floor function $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ drops all the digits after the decimal point. Now, all we have to do is move the decimal point $n$ places to the right ($\times 10^n$), apply the floor function, and move the decimal point $n$ places to the left ($\div 10^n$). Putting this together, we have:

\begin{equation}
a_n = \lfloor 10^n x_n \rfloor \div 10^n = \frac{1}{10^n} \lfloor 10^n x_n \rfloor.
\end{equation}

Clearly, $a_n$ is rational. To prove that $\{a_n\}$ is asymptotic to $\{x_n\}$, we use a basic property of the floor function:

\begin{equation}
x – 1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \leq x.
\end{equation}

Applying this to our sequence, we have:

\begin{equation}
10^n x_n – 1 < \lfloor 10^n x_n \rfloor \leq 10^n x_n.
\end{equation}

Dividing everything by $10^n$, we get:

\begin{align}
x_n - \frac{1}{10^n} &< \frac{1}{10^n} \lfloor 10^n x_n \rfloor \leq x_n, \\
x_n - \frac{1}{10^n} &< a_n \leq x_n.
\end{align}

Everything above still works if $\{10^n\}$ is replaced by any other rational sequence that tends to infinity, such as $\{n\}$:

\begin{equation}
a_n = \frac{1}{n} \lfloor n x_n \rfloor.
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! But how would the idea also work with anything other than multiplying with ${10}^n$? I guess that as $n$ gets larger then we would get the decimal sign to move more and more to the left and the process would be much slower to start being asymptotic than the one with ${10}^n$?

Comment: Is the above comment the correct idea for using numbers other than ${10}^n$?

Answer (score 0):

continued fractions give the best rational approximations to numbers.

Considering for example $0<x<1$, and let $T(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\lfloor \frac1x\rfloor$, where $\lfloor \cdot\rfloor$ is the floor function (a.k.a. maximum integer function).

Then
$$x=\frac{1}{1/x}=\frac{1}{\lfloor \frac1x\rfloor + Tx}=\frac{1}{a_1 +Tx}$$

where $a_1(x)=\lfloor \frac1x\rfloor$. Continuing this way, and as long as $T^{n-1}x=T(T^{n-2}(x))\neq0$, let $a_n(x)=\lfloor \tfrac{1}{T^{n-1}x}\rfloor$. We obtain the sequences of rational numbers
$$ x_n:=\frac{1}{a_1+\tfrac{1}{a_2 +\ddots\tfrac{1}{a_{n-1}+\tfrac{1}{a_n}}}}$$

It turns out that the rational approximations $x_n$ in some sense that can be made very precise:

0. If $x$ is rational, the sequence $x_n$ is final after a finite number of steps.

For irrational $x$, the sequence $x_n$ is infinite and

1. $x_n=\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ where
   \begin{align}
   p_n&=a_np_{n-1}+p_{n-2}\\
   q_n&=a_nq_{n-1}+q_{n-2}
   \end{align}
   with $p_0=0$, $p_1=1$, $q_0=1$ and $q_1=a_1$.
2. It is relatively easy to check that $m.c.d(p_n,q_n)=1$ for all $n\geq0$.
3. With a little more effort we have the bounded
   $$\frac{1}{q_nq_{n+2}}<\Big|x-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\Big|<\frac{1}{q_nq_{n+1}}$$

That the rational $x_n$'s are the best rational approximations to $x$ is expressed in the following result

> Theorem: If there is a rational number $a/b$ with $b>0$ such that
> $$\big|x-\frac{a}{b}\big|<\big|x-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\big|$$
> for some $n>0$, then $b>q_n$.

A classic example is the golden mean $\phi:=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ which can me expressed as
$$\phi:=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\ldots}}}$$

It is customary to use the notation $[a_1a_1\ldots]$ for the number $x$; other notations are $\frac{1}{a_1+}\frac{1}{a_2+}\cdots$.

A fun fact (easy to prove) is that if the continued fraction of a number is periodic, that is there is a pattern $a_{n_0}\cdots a_{n_0+k}$ that repeats (similar to periodic decimal expansions) then the irrational number it represents solves a quadratic question with integer coefficients, and vice versa.

Example: the golden mean $\phi$ satisfies $x=\frac{1}{1+x}$, or equivalently  $x^2+x-1=0$

Example: $\sqrt{2}-1=\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\ldots}}}$ satisfies $x=\frac{1}{2+x}$ , or equivalently $x^2+2x-1=0$

The number in your OP, $\beta=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ does not solve a quadratic equation by a quartic: $x^4-2x^2-1=0$. Its continued fraction expansion is not periodic. This requires more finesse. There are very good algorithms nowadays that can produce large amounts of integers in the continued fraction of several algebraic numbers. Here is the first 10 elements of the continued fraction of $\beta-1=[1,1,4,6,1,2,2,2,1,1,6,\ldots]$.

---

Using also fine numerical methods to solve equations, can give you approximations for algebraic and wet known transcendental numbers in decimal expansion with different levels of accuracy.

---

The answer given in the different posting of course shoes that any irrational number can be approximated by rationals. This is a trivial fact due to the density of rationals in the real line (the kind of stuff cover in a course of Calculus or undergraduate Analysis). However, it is useless in practice for it does not tells you how to approximate numbers by irrationals, and how good the approximation is.

There are irrational numbers that are hard to approximate, the golden mean $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ being the hardest (in the sense of the theorem above). It is a delicate problem in fine numerical analysis, dynamical systems, and many applications in physics to have good approximations to irrational numbers, for systems may be extremely sensitive to errors.

I hope this motivates the OP to do some digging into continued fractions. Classic high school books such as Hall, H.S. and S.R. Knight, Higher Algebra, 1889 (Now edited by USA public domain selection), and Uspenski's Theory of equations dedicate a few chapters to this topics. The classic book on the subject is a book  Perron, O.,  Die Lehre von den Kettenbrüchen, 1913. Another short and nice treatment appears in Vinogradov, I. Elements of Number Theory, English translation, Dover.

Comment: What is $T(x)$ here? Is it an irrational number or a sequence?

Comment: @Jim: $T(x)$ is the fractional part of $1/x$, as I defined it in my posting. That map has a good pedegree, and in ergodic theory and analytic number theory is call Gauss map.  You can Google continue fractions and best rational approximations. Many highschool books still cover the material. It has many important applications non only in Mathematics itself, but in Physics.

Comment: I believe you misread the question. The OP talks about finding a sequence of rationals that is asymptotic to a **sequence of irrationals** (which could or couldn't be convergent), not of a sequence of rationals converging to a fixed irrational.

Answer (score -1):

There are many rational sequences converging to any particular irrational number you start with. There is no general rule for finding one.

Since you can always find some rational number in any interval, if you simply pick $a_n$ in the interval  $(x, x+1/n)$ you will have a sequence of rationals converging to $x$.

For $\sqrt{2}$ the sequence
$$
\frac{1}{1},\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{5},\frac{17}{12},\frac{41}{29}, \ldots
$$
is the best (in a particular rigorous sense). It's the [continued fraction expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730349/convergents-of-square-root-of-2).

You can always use continued fractions, as in other answers here. For quadratic irrationals they are particularly nice.

The successively more accurate initial segments of the decimal expansion will also do.

For roots of polynomials there's [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Related: [Computing irrational numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1295373/computing-irrational-numbers/1295389#1295389)

Comment: I believe you misread the question. The OP talks about finding a sequence of rationals that is asymptotic to a **sequence of irrationals** (which could or couldn't be convergent), not of a sequence of rationals converging to a fixed irrational.